# How to query the expiry date for an RNS domain?

Tags: solidity, rsk

In addition to direct queries, I'd also like to subscribe to events to listen for whenever the expiry date changes (e.g. when it is renewed)

I've found that `NodeOwner.sol` has an
[`available` function](https://github.com/rnsdomains/rns-rskregistrar/blob/b20ce07dce3290de0b0bedcc8c8ba3aca30ea039/contracts/NodeOwner.sol#L45-L51)
whose implementation looks promising:

```
    function available(uint256 tokenId) public view returns(bool) {
        return expirationTime[tokenId] < now;
    }
```

and that same file also defines an
[`ExpirationChanged` event](https://github.com/rnsdomains/rns-rskregistrar/blob/b20ce07dce3290de0b0bedcc8c8ba3aca30ea039/contracts/NodeOwner.sol#L17):

```
    event ExpirationChanged(uint256 tokenId, uint expirationTime);
```

What I haven't been able to figure out is:

- How to get the `NodeOwner` - which contract/ address should be queried?
- If there are multiple possible addresses/ instances of `NodeOwner`, or there's only one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the expiration time of a single domain, you can use the `RSKOwner` contract with the `expirationTime` method. You can query this contract to with the domain you are interested in.

On Mainnet, the contract’s address is `0x45d3E4fB311982a06ba52359d44cB4f5980e0ef1`, which can be verified on the [RSK explorer](https://explorer.rsk.co/address/0x45d3e4fb311982a06ba52359d44cb4f5980e0ef1). The ABI for this contract can be found [here](https://github.com/rsksmart/rns-manager-react/blob/develop/src/app/tabs/newAdmin/domainInfo/abis.json).

Using Web3 library, you can query a single domain (such as testing.rsk) like this:

```js
const rskOwner = new web3.eth.Contract(rskOwnerAbi, rskOwnerAddress);

const hash = `0x${sha3('testing')}`;

rskOwner.methods.expirationTime(hash).call((error, result) => {
    console.log('expires at: ', result)
})
```

You can see a [working example of this on the RNS Manager](https://github.com/rsksmart/rns-manager-react/blob/develop/src/app/tabs/newAdmin/domainInfo/operations.js#L41-L46).